# Is Hardware Breakpoint able to write memory?

Tags: c++, assembly, hardware, breakpoints

I have this ASM Code which i would like to do a Hardware breakpoint on it, however I'm wonder if I could use Hardware Breakpoint to write the memory. Can anyone advice?

```
[ASM]
41A8BA - 68 12345678 [PUSH 78563412]
```

Is there anyway I can write it on Hardware Breakpoint that makes it to "68 00000000" for example on C++?

```
[C++ Code]
LONG WINAPI ExceptionFilter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS ExceptionInfo)
{
    if(ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP)
    {
        if((DWORD)ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionAddress == 0x41A8BA)
        {
            //What do i write here?
            return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
        }
    }
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}
```

Comment: In other words, you'd like to modify an instruction before it's executed?

Comment: I would like to modify an instruction in hardware level if possible (I'm not sure if Hardware Breakpoint can do this), before executed, yes.

Comment: By "hardware level", do you mean that you want to change the instruction without the change being visible in memory?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: That's not really what exceptions are for. You should probably explain your root problem instead of explaining the problem you have with the solution you're currently attempting. Have you considered using a debugger and scripting it?

Comment: I was trying to code a simple dll for this "Protected" application, which I realised that by doing simple Memory Editing on this line (eg. 41A8BA - 68 12345678), it switches off certain functions/security of the code. However if i were to do it via the writeprocessmemory, the server side crc check will detect this and hence crash the application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hardware Breakpoint Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522056/hardware-breakpoint-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm very familiar with how x86's implementation of hardware breakpoints work (from "what it does to the processor" - not how it's actually designed internally), and have read the descriptions for several others.

Hardware breakpoints do not DO anything to the code in question - it is a set of special registers, that can be given a pattern ("Address X, trigger on write", "Address Y, trigger on execute"), which are checked against during the execution of the code, and if there is a match (e.g. "Address X is being written to" or "Address Y is being executed"), then the processor will stop executing and enter an exception handler - at which point the software in the exception handler takes over, typically by handing over to the debugger to say "Your code did a write to address X, here's where you are at" or "Your code executed address Y, here's where we stopped".

The hardware brekapoints can't directly be used to read, write or execute anything - it's just a "match + exception" mechanism. Technically, one could make the exception handler do something like writing to the address being executed, but that would not be "the hardware breakpoint", and it would still be treated just like any other code executing on the processor, meaning the memory has to be mapped in a way that it can be written (code, typically, isn't writeable in modern OS's such as Windows and Linux).

You can of course, in the exception handler for the debug break, map the memory as writeable (if needed), and write a different value to the part of code you care about (if it's in another process, you need to use `OpenProcess` and `WriteProcessMemory`)  - again, this is nothing directly to do with hardware breakpoints, but about the code executed as a consequence, and will still follow the usual rules of the OS with regards to what memory you can read and write.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering what this has to do with hardware breakpoints.

Is far as I understand you want to modify a Windows program when it is stopped?

To do this you should use the "WriteProcessMemory()" API function.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, but I would like to modify it on a hardware level.

Comment: Maybe, that's why my question was "I wonder if I could use Hardware Breakpoint to write the memory."